# Rest assured - Can't reuse reponse token

Tags: rest, get, rest-assured, jsonobjectrequest

I need to create a requests for Rest testing.
I've created some simple tests, login, create accound,...
But now it's more complicated for me.

My example of a request looks like that:

```
    JSONObject childJSON = new JSONObject();
    childJSON.put("email", "user@yahoo.com");
    childJSON.put("password", "1asdaasx");

    JSONObject request = new JSONObject();
    request.put("user", childJSON);
    
    String token = given().
        auth().
        basic("login", "password").
        header("Content-Type", "application/json").
        body(request).
     when().
        post("https://BASEuri.com/api/users/login").
     then().
        statusCode(200).
        .log().all()
        .extract().path("user.token").toString();

 }
```

**REPONSE**
`{ "user": { "username": "user", "email": "user@yahoo.com", "token": "eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJpZCI6IjYwYWNmOGMzNjkzMTg1OWE1ZWVkNjQzMSIsInVsdcalIjoicGkyc3FyMiIsImV4cCI6MTYyNzY3ODE4MiwiaWF0IjoxNjIyNDk0MTgyfQ.a4kfaLbQgO0y-8MRx69O4SOSasdw4XCkMvhetDkG3w", "bio": "123", "image": "" } }`

Now I need to take the token and pass it to the next request?
According to spec

**API SPEC**

> Update user PUT /api/user Example {   "user":{
> "email": "me@me.com",
> "bio": "I like music",
> "image": "https://i.stack.imgur.com/qwe.jpg"   } }

**Second request**

```
JSONObject childJSONSub = new JSONObject();      
childJSONSub.put("email", "user@yahoo.com");          
childJSONSub.put("bio", "My New Bio");       
childJSONSub.put("image", "https://i.stack.imgur.com/sad3.jpg");  

JSONObject requestSub = new JSONObject();        
requestSub.put("user", childJSONSub); 

given().            
    auth().             
    basic("login", "password").             
    header("Content-Type", "application/json").          
    queryParam("Authorization", token).             
    body(requestSub).        
when().             
    put("https://BASEuri.com/api/user").         
then().    
    log().all();
```

But the answer is like that:

```
"errors": {
    "message": "No authorization token was found",
    "error": {
        "name": "UnauthorizedError",
        "message": "No authorization token was found",
        "code": "credentials_required",
        "status": 401,
        "inner": {
            "message": "No authorization token was found"
        }
    }
}
```

Any suggestions?
I've tried multiple solutions for token but always wi the same result.

Answer (score 0):

You will need an access token to be authorized to access this feature

This access token is made available in different ways depending on the API

Probably there is some endpoint to get the token

In order to help you more, I would need more information about the problem

Comment: Some Actions gave me a response with token but even when trying to extract it, it does not work. This solution is not working for me: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44854145/rest-assured-how-to-extract-generated-token-from-response-body-after-post-reque